# C# AForge, program freezes at learning stage

Tags: c#, neural-network, aforge

I'm playing around with AForge. I copypasted the example from AForge website.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using AForge;
using AForge.Neuro;
using AForge.Math;
using AForge.Neuro.Learning;

namespace NeuralNetTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // initialize input and output values
            double[][] input = new double[4][] {
                new double[] {0, 0}, new double[] {0, 1},
                new double[] {1, 0}, new double[] {1, 1}
            };

            double[][] output = new double[4][] {
                new double[] {0}, new double[] {1},
                new double[] {1}, new double[] {0}
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Tworzę sieć neuronową...");
            // create neural network
            ActivationNetwork network = new ActivationNetwork(
                new SigmoidFunction(2),
                2, // two inputs in the network
                2, // two neurons in the first layer
                1); // one neuron in the second layer
            // create teacher
            BackPropagationLearning teacher = new BackPropagationLearning(network);
            Console.WriteLine("Sieć neuronowa uczy się...");
            while (true)
            {
                double error = teacher.RunEpoch(input, output);
                if (error < 0.001) break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Uczenie sieci neuronowej zakończone.");
            Console.WriteLine("Sieć jest gotowa obliczać XOR.");

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wpisz pierwszy bajt: (0 lub 1):");
                double f1 = (double)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("Wpisz drugi bajt: (0 lub 1):");
                double f2 = (double)Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                double[] netout = network.Compute(new double[2] { f1, f2 });
                Console.WriteLine("{0} XOR {1} to {2}.", (int)f1, (int)f2, netout[0]);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see it should be able to compute XOR of two bits.
How ever. It freezes on learning! It was working fine, but now it freezes everytime when the error is 0.26981832999407546.

It was working. And now, BOOM, it doesn't work, what the hell?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I left it learning for like a hour... it freezed at ~0.3-something

Comment: Today, when I run it, it mostly work, but only sometimes it freezes. Maybe my AI became self aware, and it doesn't want to learn the same thing all the time? :s

Answer (score 0):

It maybe failed to converge, you can set the learning rate `teacher.LearningRate` that has the default value 0.1 to a lower number.

Another note that your program freeze during learning process because it takes time, you can run the training on another separate thread.

I have a good demonstration using AForge.NET and Accord.NET, take a [look](https://github.com/ammar-lakis/NNSamples).